# How to start using react on existing django website

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

My team developed a django website with lot of pages that working completely without javascript or may be with the little jquery manipulation. We want try to use a react library to speed up our pages and add page navigation without full page reloading (we choose react because we implemented some SPA website with react and we like it). Also our pages should working with disable js.

I want to start with one page with 5 forms on it. If any form is submit then page is reloaded, data populated in fields is lost and it work slowly.  I think to implementing sending data on ajax and change some html after server answer.

Every react tutorial is saying to write jsx components with html markup inside, convert it with babel to pure js and adding on page dynamically on page load. Or if you want to render pages on server you need to use standalone node server. But I already has a powerfull django template engine to render templates on server side, also I need to render templates with specific django things like multilanguage content, user variables etc.

Can I fully render page with django on server side and after loading say to react, that specific div it's a component with initial state and existing html markup? Or may be you can tell me another solution, without fully rewriting my website. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, kind of. Every react app starts by specifying a root HTML element to render from.  If you want to only render a portion of your website with react, just specify an element that covers the section that you want.  Something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyMainComponent />, document.getElementById('myReactSection'));
```

However, in doing so, any existing HTML in there will be overwritten (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render).  So you'll need React to re-render the html that was already in there.

Also, you don't **NEED** babel to write react code, it's just very useful (in conjunction with [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)) to generate a single javascript bundle file to send over to the client that was originally written using the awesome new ES6 syntax (https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/)

Comment: Any thoughts (or references) on whats the "ideal" approach? Completely replacing Django templates with React or render only parts of the page with React and use Django template engine for the rest of it? I have been reading a lot lately on how to integrate React with Django and it seems these two approaches are quite different from each other. Happy to hear @taylorc93's or other people's thoughts